# Entity Framework and insert with an Identity column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, identity

I'm using Entity Framework for a Windows Forms project. My database has two tables, `Table A` and `Table B`.

`Table A` has an identity column `PkId`. Table B also has an identity column (`PkId`) and also `FkIdA` which is a foreign key to table A.

If I add a new row in table A, it gets a PkId of 0. I will then add a new row in table B, that points to that new row in table A. That is expected.

Now if the user adds another row in table A, it will get the same Id (0). And then he will add more rows in table B pointing to the same Id. Once I call `DbContext.SaveChanges()`, the application will crash because Table A.PkId is not unique (makes sense).

I've worked with `Dataset` before, and it gave local Ids, starting from 0 or -1 and going decremental (so -1, -2, -3, etc.). How can I make sure Entity follows the same rule ?

The reason I don't call `SaveChanges` between each insert in order to retrieve the true `PkId` given by the database is because I want to offer the possibility to delete the changes done to the user (and thus, once he commits, he should not be able to revert what has been done).

## Edit

I added a picture of my model. I also went and checked the `PkId` column of table A (`Transaction`) and its stored generated pattern is Identity, as expected.

[image]

## Edit 2

The auto-generated model from entity contains a reference to payments within `Transaction`

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
```

Now the way I add a new `WholeTransaction`, which is basically a Transaction with 2 payments is like this:

```
var newWholeTransaction = new AddNewTransaction();
newWholeTransaction.ShowDialog();

if (!newWholeTransaction.WasSaved)
    return;

var transaction = DbContext.Transactions.Add(newWholeTransaction.WholeTransaction.Transaction);

newWholeTransaction.WholeTransaction.PaymentJeanne.FkIdTransaction = transaction.Id;
newWholeTransaction.WholeTransaction.PaymentLuis.FkIdTransaction = transaction.Id;

DbContext.Payments.Add(newWholeTransaction.WholeTransaction.PaymentJeanne);
DbContext.Payments.Add(newWholeTransaction.WholeTransaction.PaymentLuis);
```

Comment: What do the entities look like? I've never had to worry about the Ids of the rows. It should be able to figure out what's new and associated and handle it automagically.

Comment: Do you want a picture of my model ?

Comment: Entity Framework set ids from 1 and then increment it. Zero means it isn't added to database.

Comment: you are getting 0 ids because you dont save changes. means it isn't added to database.

Comment: @Lana indeed, as long as I keep adding rows to my table and I don't call SaveChanges, Ids are all 0. The issue happens if you have a foreign key, then entity can't assume the link since Ids are all the same. I thought it would use the navigation properties, since they contain the reference, but it seems it does not. I'll add the error message, hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework manages PkIds, not you.

```
var transaction1 = new Transaction();
transaction1.Name = "tr1";

var transaction2 = new Transaction();
transaction2.Name = "tr2";

var payment1 = new Payment();
payment1.Amount = 1;
payment1.Transaction = transaction1;

var payment2 = new Payment();
payment2.Amount = 1;
payment2.Transaction = transaction2;

context.Transactions.Insert(transaction1);
context.Transactions.Insert(transaction2);
context.Payments.Insert(payment1);
context.Payments.Insert(payment2);

context.SaveChanges();
```

another way;

```
transaction1.Payments.Add(payment1);
transaction2.Payments.Add(payment2);
```

Comment: I see, I should've updated the navigation property instead of adding it myself. Like this
`transaction.Payments.Add(newWholeTransaction.WholeTransaction.PaymentJeanne);`

Answer (score 1):

As usual I use Navigation properties for these things

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OtherId { get; set; }
    public OtherEntity Other { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would expect Entity use the navigation properties, I'll show you the piece of code I have

Comment: @RegularNormalDayGuy var entityToAdd = new MyEntity(){ Other= new OtherEntity() {set its properties here}}; this code works